# How to detect current device using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, uikit, swiftui

I am trying to determine whether the device being used is iPhone or iPad.

Please see this question: [Detect current device with UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059327/detect-current-device-with-ui-user-interface-idiom-in-swift)

That solution works if you use UIKit. But

What is the equivalent method if you are using SwiftUI ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can find the device type, like this:

```swift
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you do so in SwiftUI ?

Comment: You cannot use it without import UIKit.

Comment: Xcode complains to me saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'UIDevice'. It goes away only if I import UIKit

Comment: I import the following: import Foundation
import SwiftUI

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? It works for me too with just `import SwiftUI`

Comment: @KaizerSozay check this post on more information on how to use the code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57652242/how-to-detect-whether-targetenvironment-is-ipados-in-swiftui

Comment: This doesn't work with SwiftUI only, it requires UIKit so it doesn't work on a macOS device.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this:

```
UIDevice.current.localizedModel
```

In your case, an implementation method could be:

```
if UIDevice.current.localizedModel == "iPhone" {
     print("This is an iPhone")
} else if UIDevice.current.localizedModel == "iPad" {
     print("This is an iPad")
}
```

Obviously, you can use this for string interpolation such as this (assuming the current device type is an iPhone):

```
HStack {
     Text("Device Type: ")
     Text(UIDevice.current.localizedModel)
}

//Output:
//"Device Type: iPhone"
```

It will return the device type. (iPhone, iPad, AppleWatch) No further imports are necessary aside from SwiftUI which should have already been imported upon creation of your project if you selected SwiftUI as the interface.

NOTE: It does not return the device model (despite the ".localizedModel")

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

UIDevice is no longer available from WatchKit 2 on

**WKInterfaceDevice** could be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice

i.e.:

```
let systemName = WKInterfaceDevice.current().systemName
let systemVersion = WKInterfaceDevice.current().systemVersion
let deviceModel = WKInterfaceDevice.current().model
```