# Separate iPad and iPhone Apps with Xcode and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a question about Xcode. I'm trying to create an App for all Apple Platforms. IOS, MacOS, WatchOS and TVOS. I know how to set up a Multiplatform app but the problem I am facing right now is how I separate the iPhone and iPad App to meet apples preferred iPadOS design expectations like a sidebar or something. Do I have to set it up in Code or in Xcode and how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect current device using SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113923/how-to-detect-current-device-using-swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the current device and then change the interface depending on if your user uses an iPhone or iPad.

To check if it is an iPad, use

```
if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { }
```

Just replace the `.pad` with `.phone` to check for an iPhone.