# UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom is phone even while running the app on an iPad

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, ipad

#### Problem:

If I deselect iPad as a device that I want to deploy to, as shown below:
[image]

and then run my app using debug/TestFlight on my iPad, `UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57669057/11104068)) returns `phone` instead of `pad`.

#### Question:

How can I detect that the app is running on an iPad in this state?

#### Context

The problem is that this [Stair Climber app](https://stairmasterclimber.com/), that you can [test here](https://testflight.apple.com/join/rVmdwYce) requires HealthKit to work, and iPads don't have the Health app, so I can't pull in Flights Climbed data into the app, so the app is basically useless. And even though I deselect iPad and don't add iPad pictures to the listing, the App Store review team rejected me for the UX on iPads -,-. That is why I want the user to have a different experience if they are not using iPhones.

Comment: Have you tried including the iPad? Since you already want to deal with the difference, you should include the iPad. A word of warning, though. The reviewers use iPads (which is why you were rejected) so you need to be acutely aware of the functionality on iPads.

Comment: Yes of course when I include the iPad, it does show up as `pad`, but I don't want to include the iPad as I mentioned. Is there any other way of knowing whether a device is an iPad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom` is not about device but about currently active *interface idiom* of the supported, but which you actually turned off.

You can use `UIDevice.current.model` property to detect if real device is iPad.